# How to multiply a loop using a tuple, but doing it 1 index at a time?

Tags: python, list, loops, nested, tuples

Im trying to make a program that lets you input the amount of dollar bills you have of each bill type than multiplying that by the value of those bill types.

This is my first try

```
 hundred = 100
 _100 = int(input("How many hundred dollar bills do you have? "))
 fifty = 50
 _50 = int(input("How many fifty dollar bills do you have? "))
 #then I do this with 20s, 10s, 5s, etc

money = (hundred * _100) + (fifty * _50) + (twenty * _20) + (ten * _10) + (five * _5) + (one * _1)
print(f"You have a total of ${money}, dont spend it all!")
```

It worked but I feel like it was very basic, repeated its self, and lacked any real skill to create. Then in my studies I started to learn loops and really thought I could implement them into this project.

```
    total = 0
    value = (100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1)

    dollars = ("How many hundred dollar bills do you have? ", "How many fifty dollar bills do you have? ",
       "How many twenty dollar bills do you have? ", "How many ten dollar bills do you have? ",
       "How many five dollar bills do you have? ", "How many one dollar bills do you have? ")

    for money in dollars:
        amount = int(input(money))
        for worth in value:
            total = (worth * amount + total)
    print(total)
```

I feel like I've almost figured it out but I'm so stuck because my nested loop multiples all the number in my tuple(value) by what ever the user inputs I don't know how to separate it so it multiplies for example (100 * the input for 100s). The only thing Ive thought of Is separating them by index ex. ([1:2]) but I feel like id just be repeating my self for no reason.

Help please, I'm a server and its very nice to have your computer count your money for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for money, worth in zip(dollars, value):
    amount = int(input(money))
    total += worth * amount
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a dictionary in this situation.

```
total = 0
dollars = {"hundred": 100, "fifty": 50, "twenty": 20, "ten": 10, "five": 5, "one": 1}
for prompt, money in dollars.items():
    n = int(input(f'How many {prompt} dollar bills do you have? '))
    total = money * n + total
print(total)
```

Output:

```
How many hundred dollar bills do you have? 2
How many fifty dollar bills do you have? 3
How many twenty dollar bills do you have? 0
How many ten dollar bills do you have? 0
How many five dollar bills do you have? 1
How many one dollar bills do you have? 1
356
```